# swagger - extract parameter info from express-validation

Tags: node.js, swagger, express-validator

I'm new to node, swagger etc.
I'm working on a node.js app, I added some endpoints and using express-validation package I configured validators for my end points.

I now started using also swagger-autogen to generate swagger doc, but I can't find a way to make swagger use the validators in order to provide more data/limitations of the endpoints' parameters.

Is there a way to achieve something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have exact same question right now. Did you find a solution?

Comment: it's been a long time and I switched jobs so no access to my solution, but I think I eventually created a validation scheme from express-validation and loaded it into swagger. pretty sure it was something like that. there was a swagger init code or something like that that read that schema. sorry I can't help more than that